# unexpected output

Tags: arduino-uno, c++

I wrote some arduino code but since I don't have access to an arduino, ran it on a tinkercad circuit, the code is supposed to set all the buttons values to 1 and all the password values to 0 and the output "false password" as per the checkpassword function, but instead is outputting an infinite line of ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ.
here is my code:

```
int i;
int passTrue[9];
int buttons[] {};


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(2, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(3, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(4, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(5, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(6, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(7, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(8, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(9, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(10,INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}

int * SetButtons() {
  for (int i = 1; i<=9; ++i) {
    buttons[i] = digitalRead(i);
 }
  return buttons;
}     


int * SetPass() {
  i = 0;
  for (i = 1; i<=9; ++i) {
     if(buttons[i] == LOW) {
      passTrue[i] = buttons[i];
     }
  }
return passTrue;
}
  
  void CheckPass() {
    for(i=1; i<=9; ++i) {
      if(passTrue[i] != buttons[i]) {
        Serial.println("false Password");
      } else {
        Serial.println("correct password");
      }
    }
  }

void Test() {
  for(i=1; i<=9; ++i) {
   buttons[i] = 0;
   passTrue[i] = 1;
  }
}

  void loop() {
SetButtons();
SetPass();
Test();
CheckPass();
  
  }
```

it shouldn't be relevant but attached is also my circuit:
[image]

Comment: `int buttons[] {};` - I've got a bad news for you - this is not doing what you think it does

Comment: And also passTrue has 9 elements and the first element is on index 0. But you are starting on second element and accessing one element after the array (Welcome to the Buffer overflow world).

Comment: `ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ` usually indicates a baud rate mismatch.

Comment: Since TinkerCAD handles baud rate matching automatically that is not the problem.  But  your buttons array looks problematic. My hunch is that you are corrupting memory and it's causing weird printing behaviour.

Comment: Just take `int buttons [9];` instead of `int buttons [] {};` and it should work.